# Updating iLO on and old server

Tags: hp, ilo, firmware

I have an old HP ProLiant DL380 G3 server I plan on using to tamper with. However, I have ran into an issue.

I can't access iLO due to a firmware gap (from around 2003) to the present.

When I try to login to my iLO panel, it first sends me to a page that tells me I need to accept a security certificate. Then I assume it redirects me to this page I need to accept the certificate on.

When it redirects me, I get this error in my browser:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

10.0.0.2 uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.
```

Now, I've tried to enable these old SSLv3 cipers, and even go back to out-dated browsers to try and access the iLO control panel, but nothing works. I get the same error no matter what.

How do I update the iLO firmware to a more recent version of SSL, to allow me to connect?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The ILO is old and out of support because the server is old and out of support.

The HP ProLiant DL380 G3 dates back to *2003*, so you're talking about 13 year-old equipment.

You can download the software to update your ILO from *within* your operating system environment by going to [HP's support site](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=397990&lang=en&cc=us). The current version is **1.96** from 2014.

Another option is using something like the [hpilo_cli utility](http://seveas.github.io/python-hpilo/#quick-usage-examples) to load your firmware.

---

Connect a mouse and keyboard to the server and install your OS. ILO is not a prerequisite to using this hardware.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to get passed the outdated security certs?

Comment: You asked how to update your ILO's firmware. My answer above links you to the [firmware updates](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=397990&swItemId=MTX_c2868937e6e444b8ba65f1fb1b&swEnvOid=2025#tab4) for the ILO vintage you're working with.

Comment: I don't have access to an operating system on the server, that's why I need iLO.

Comment: It doesn't have a VGA port and either PS/2 or USB ports for a keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Install your favorite server OS on it manually to update iLO. It's not as though you have 10,000 of these to update remotely.